# Check XML node have attribute name with specific value - Parse XML using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing

First I apologize  for creating a new question about XML parsing using Linq

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"
    xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>       
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="epub.css"/> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav epub:type="toc" id="toc">          
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <a href="text.xhtml">The System</a>
                </li>   
                    <li>
                    <a href="text1.xhtml">The Option</a>
                </li>   
            </ol>           
        </nav>
           <nav epub:type="landmarks" id="guide">
            .......
            .......
           </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to check `nav` tag having the attribute `epub:type` with value `toc` & which get into  &

tags collect all  tag info.

To achieve this I started to get the `<nav>` tag which having attreibute `epub:type` with value `toc`

```
        var xDoc = XDocument.Load("nav.xhtml");
        var result = (from ele in xDoc.Descendants("nav") select ele).ToList();

        foreach (var t in result)
        {
            if (t.Attributes("epub:type").Any())
            {
                var dev = t.Attribute("epub:type").Value;
            }
        }
```

But every time the `result` count is zero. I wonder what is the wrong in my XML.

Can you please suggest me right way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a namespace problem. You're looking for `nav` elements without specifying a namespace, but the default namespace is `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`. Additionally, you're looking for your epub attributes in the wrong way.

I suggest you change your code to:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("nav.xhtml");
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
XNamespace epub = "http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops";

foreach (var t in xDoc.Descendants(ns + "nav"))
{
    var attribute = t.Attribute(epub + "type");
    if (attribute != null)
    {
        ... use the attribute
    }
}
```

Or if you want to modify the result in your `if` statement, just call `.ToList()` at the end of the `Descendants` call:

```
foreach (var t in xDoc.Descendants(ns + "nav").ToList())
```